# Cannot find icons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I am using rails3 with bootstrap-sass gem.

I'm having an error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/img/glyphicons-halflings.png"):
```

my **bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss** is:

```
@import "bootstrap";
body { padding-top: 60px; }
@import "bootstrap-responsive";
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require paloma
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: No route matches [GET] "/img/glyphicons-halflings.png" means that you have not added any images in img foler in assets glyphicons-halflings.png

Answer (score 2):

try this code in `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss`, if you use `gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"`

```
 @import "twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap";
 @import "twitter/bootstrap/responsive";

// Set the correct sprite paths
@iconSpritePath: asset-path("twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings.png");
@iconWhiteSpritePath: asset-path("twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-white.png");
```